# Exception: defaultEndpoint must be specified. For camel AWS SES for direct:start

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel

I am not able to set the default endpoint using annotation. As per the camel docs, it recommends annotation as shown below.

```
// auto wiring a producer template using endpoint annotation
@Autowired
@EndpointInject(uri="direct:start")
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

// send the body
producerTemplate.sendBody("hi");
```

Doesn't work. It still complains

> "Exception: defaultEndpoint must be specified"

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Realising this is an old question I have answered this none the less as I found your question when trying to fix this issue in a test.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the defaultEndpoint on the ProducerTemplate itself, so something like:

```
// set the defautlEndPoint
producerTemplate.setDefaultEndpointUri("direct:start");
// send the body
producerTemplate.sendBody("hi");
```